# PostgreSQL gives me "connection refused" even if "listen_addresses = '*'"

Tags: postgresql, database-connection

I have a new DigitalOcean Droplet where I set up a Postgres Database that I am trying to access from my local machine (via pd.read_sql_query). I have not been able to establish a connection with the Droplet, and I have no idea where I'm in the wrong. I've changed both my pg_config and pg_hba files and restarted my psql server.

Here is my pg_hba file:

[image]

Here is my pg_config:

[image]

Here is the output on my Droplet when I run

```
netstat -nlt
```

[image]

My theory is that for some reason port 5432 is only listening for local connections. For reference here is the output for ls_pgclusters:

[image]

Lastly here is the output I get when I try to connect to the server:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>psql -h xxx.xx.xxx.xxx -p 5432 -d dbName -U postgres
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I don't know what else there is to do to connect to the server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Postgres server only listens on the loopback interface. You need to change `listen_addresses` to make it also listen on other interfaces. If you then still cannot connect, temporarily deactivate any firewall and try again. If you can connect when the firewall is disabled, then you need to make a rule in the firewall that allows the connection before reenabling the firewall. But that said, I'd rather recommend using a VPN or [SSH tunnel](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssh-tunnels.html) than connecting directly and this is not a programming question, i.e. off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed `listen_addresses` to `*`, but you forgot to remove the comment (`#`) at the beginning of the line, so the parameter is still at its default value `localhost`.

Remove the `#` and restart PostgreSQL.