# Error connecting server to DigitalOcean Postgresql droplet

Tags: postgresql, server, connection-string, digital-ocean, prisma

I am aware that I can connect to a pre-configured Digital Ocean PostgreSQL database cluster and that's what I'm actually connected to right now, but I'd like to connect to a droplet instead (It's cheaper). The droplet is running Ubuntu and came set up with Node JS, PM2, and Nginx. I have already Installed postgreSQL and set up a database on it.

I try to connect to the droplet with this connection string:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<DROPLET-IP-ADDRESS>:5432/<DBNAME>?schema=public"
```

and this is the error im getting:

```
Can't reach database server at `<DROPLET-IP-ADDRESS>`:`5432`\n\nPlease make sure your database server is running at `<DROPLET-IP-ADDRESS>`:`5432`.",
```

Whats the correct way of connecting via Prisma to a DigitalOcean droplet

Comment: Are you able to access the Postgres instance inside the droplet from your local machine through other means? One possible way to confirm would be to try connecting to the databse through the [connection URI method](https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting) of [node-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)

Comment: yes, im able to access the postgresql database when i ssh into the dropplet

Comment: did you configure listen_addresses?

Comment: Yeah i already changed those

Answer (score 0):

If you changed `listen_addresses` to `*`, but forgotten to remove the comment (`#`) at the beginning of the line, the parameter will still be at its default value `localhost`. Check that the `#` is removed and restart PostgreSQL. Quite common mistake.

Also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67428442/5124710) by someone.